# Ubuntu server Switch python version 3.8.6 to 3.8.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, server, operating-system

I am running python version 3.8.6 on my ubuntu server os. I was wondering how I could get version 3.8.1 on my Ubuntu server os?

Comment: May I ask for the reason?

Comment: I think there may be an issue with my 3.8.6 I want to test code on 3.8.1 to see if that fixes my issue

Comment: Please present the issue, not your solution attempt.

Comment: That's not what I asked tho. I didn't ask to fix my issue. I asked how I can switch from 3.8.6 to 3.8.1 on an ubuntu server os

Comment: I would try using these instructions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/682869/how-do-i-install-a-different-python-version-using-apt-get Found by googling "ubuntu install python specific version" 3rd answer looks promising, the one with markdown and 4 steps

Answer (score 1):

Try using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.8.1
```